# How to perform integration test of a backbone app

Tags: unit-testing, testing, backbone.js, selenium, integration-testing

I want to perform integration testing i.e. automated testing for my backbone app using Selenium and Mocha but the problem I am encountering is that the selenium's webdriver looks for the html elements in the source code of the page, but in my app I am rendering the page using the views so there is no information of the elements in the source code of the particular page.

Like this: `driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('password')).sendKeys("password");`

Consider the login functionality: I have two text fields, username and password with the same id, webdriver tries to look for these elements through the id in the source code but that is not present, and hence my test fails citing "No such element".

How should I move forward in order to perform integration test for my app?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that webdriver is looking in the _source code_ for these elements? Webdriver is built to talk to the browser, which should be looking in its DOM.  Perhaps the real problem is that your automated test is not waiting long enough for the view to render?